# Failed to free a colormap entry in Xlib with XFreeColors()

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I allocate a color entry with the next code, then I use it to draw correctly:

```
char *color_name = "red";
XColor color, exact;

XAllocNamedColor(display, colormap, color_name, &color, &exact);
```

Then, when I don't need anymore the color entry, I try to free it:

```
XFreeColors(display, colormap, &color.pixel, 1, 0);
```

This call generates the next error:

```
 Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
 Major opcode of failed request:  88 (X_FreeColors)
 Serial number of failed request:  17
 Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? How can I free that color entry? That color entry should be freed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I was doing two call to XFreeColors:

```
XFreeColors(display, colormap, &color.pixel, 1, 0);
XFreeColors(display, colormap, &exact.pixel, 1, 0);
```

The second call with exact must not be done, it's not necessary.